# Laravel trying to query relatinship model hasMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following tables in my application:

`projects`
`projects_plot_types`

Projects can have many plot types.  I have the following relationship setup in the projects model.

```
/**
 * The plot types that belong to the project.
 *
 * @return Object
 */
public function plotTypes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project\ProjectsPlotTypes');
}
```

I want to be able to get the plot type by querying it's name on the project model.

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
$project->with('plotTypes')->whereHas('plotTypes', function ($query) use ($row) { 
    $query->where('name', $row->plot_name);
})->first()->plotTypes->first()->id;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

The output of `$result` as per below comment is:

```
  Project {#705 ▼
    #table: "projects"
    #fillable: array:7 [▶]
    +timestamps: true
    #connection: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    #attributes: array:10 [▶]
    #original: array:10 [▶]
    #relations: array:1 [▼
      "plotTypes" => Collection {#769 ▼
        #items: array:1 [▼
          0 => ProjectsPlotTypes {#774 ▼
            #table: "projects_plot_types"
            #fillable: array:2 [▶]
            +timestamps: false
            #connection: null
            #primaryKey: "id"
            #perPage: 15
            +incrementing: true
            #attributes: array:4 [▼
              "id" => "2"
              "project_id" => "1"
              "name" => "TYPE 3 - VENTILATION"
              "budget" => "245.69"
            ]
            #original: array:4 [▶]
            #relations: []
            #hidden: []
            #visible: []
            #appends: []
            #guarded: array:1 [▶]
            #dates: []
            #dateFormat: null
            #casts: []
            #touches: []
            #observables: []
            #with: []
            #morphClass: null
            +exists: true
            +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use join query like below

```
$result = Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('projects')
        ->join('projects_plot_types', 'projects_plot_types.id', '=', 'projects.project_plot_id')
        ->where('projects_plot_types.name', '=', $row->plot_name)
        ->first();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
$result = $project->with(['plotTypes' => function($query) use ($row) {
    return $query->where('name', $row->plot_name)->first();
}])->first();

dd($result); // print the result and die
```

**UPDATE 1**

Fetch the first item from the collection that has `BelongsTo` relationship:

```
$plotTypeResult = $result->plotTypes[0]->id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I then access the plotTypes id?  `$result->id` will print the project id presumably?

Comment: `$result->plotTypes()->first()->id` should get it what you are looking for.

Comment: This code still doesn't seem to be fetching the row that I need.

Comment: what you get when you do `dd($result);` ? update your question with the output.

Comment: It always seems to be getting the first result in the `plot_types` table irrespective of whether it matches the plot name or not?

Comment: Okay. What is the relationship between the models ? `One-To-Many` it has to be, right ? A single project has many `project_plot_types`, right ?

Comment: I have updated my question with the dd output of `$result`.  It seems the correct row is being returned in the relationship, but when I do `$result->plotTypes()->first()->id` it should output an id of `2`, but instead it outputs and id of `1`.

Comment: Try this : `$result->plotTypes[0]->id` and see what you get ?

Comment: Yes, this now gives correct output - is this the best way to achieve the correct `id`?

Comment: Yes. It is.. I do like this only.. I haven't came across any issues as such yet.. So, yes, it is the best way.. And kindly accept the answer, once you have solved it..